# WPF - Debugging touch event without touchscreen?

Tags: wpf, touchscreen

I wondering is It the way to debug/test touch event in WPF without touchscreen?
I have VS2013 and on Windows Stre App i can run a simulator or connect to remote device to test touch but i cant find this options in WPF aplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you have touch device:

You need use remote debugger.

My example with minimum settings in project:

1) On remote machine install RemoteDebugger for VS2013. Run it.

2) Create directories for project's files like on main machine. (Example: C:\projs\proj1\bin\debug). Share dir (Example: share "debug" like "proj1debug") for read and write.

2) In project's settings switch on "Use remote machine" (in "Debug") and enter remote machine name.

3) And add in Post-build event

```
copy "$(TargetDir)" "\\RemoteMachineName\proj1debug" /y
```

That's all.

If you haven't device - use [multitouchvista](https://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/)